# Where are AWS WAF API calls documented?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I would like to put an AWS WAF in front of a web site served by CloudFront. I will need to update this WAF via automated calls though its API.

**Where is this API documented?**

I quickly found the [Making HTTPS Requests to AWS WAF or Shield Advanced](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-api-making-requests.html) page, which states that

> Many AWS WAF and Shield Advanced API actions require you to include
>   JSON-formatted data in the body of the request.

This is followed by a random example of how to insert an IP match condition rule.

I cannot believe that this is the only "documentation" available (making the REST interface hardly usable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the api documentation for WAF http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_Operations_AWS_WAF.html

Answer (score 0):

and this if you are using Python https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html